# Posts not showing content after migration

Tags: posts, migration

I recently transferred a huge custom database of about 100,000 articles to wordpress. Everything seemed to work. But recently while checking the site. I found this issue where the post is displayed but when clicked, it doesn't open. Somehow the link doesn't contain the post title. Although when I edit the post and update it, it works. Now the problem is that it is very time consuming to bulk update 100 posts each time. Is there another way?

I have tried to update the permalink settings but no use.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did the posts have (or get) valid URLs when you imported them?

Comment: To be honest (and my sincere apologies), I do not understand the question. The transfer was majorly carried out via database transfer. I am not sure if I saw a field to insert post URL.

Comment: (That is what I mean, yes.) Can you look in the database to see if these posts have URLs now?

Comment: What table and column should I be looking? I just checked wp_posts and did not find any column that would suggests it is for URL

Comment: That would be the column `guid`.

Comment: Some posts have them and some don't. But some posts that do not have them also work. While some posts have their guids as the media attachment in the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93645/discussion-between-byte-it-antwerpen-and-jos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Jos](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/148766/jos) the reason for this was that the `post_name` column in the `wp_posts` table was empty. To correct the said problem, the following steps were taken:

1. Backup the database.
2. Check for duplicates in the database. `select * from (select count(*) as c, post_title from wp_posts where post_name = '' and post_type = 'post') as counts where c > 1;`
3. Update the table `wp_posts set post_name = replace(post_title, ' ', '-');`
4. Be extra careful that your `post_name` column doesn't contain accented characters or characters that are not allowed in the urls.
5. I then replaced most of the disallowed character in the `post_name` by running the following query (Absolute noob in sql):

```sql
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Š','S');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'š','s');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ð','Dj');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ž','Z');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ž','z');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'À','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Á','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Â','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ã','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ä','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Å','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Æ','A');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ç','C');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'È','E');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'É','E');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ê','E');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ë','E');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ì','I');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Í','I');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Î','I');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ï','I');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ñ','N');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ò','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ó','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ô','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Õ','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ö','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ø','O');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ù','U');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ú','U');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Û','U');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ü','U');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ý','Y');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Þ','B');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ß','Ss');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'à','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'á','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'â','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ã','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ä','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'å','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'æ','a');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ç','c');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'è','e');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'é','e');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ê','e');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ë','e');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ì','i');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'í','i');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'î','i');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ï','i');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ð','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ñ','n');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ò','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ó','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ô','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'õ','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ö','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ø','o');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ù','u');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ú','u');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'û','u');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ý','y');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ý','y');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'þ','b');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ÿ','y');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ƒ','f');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'.','-');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'-','-');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'--','-');

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ě','e');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ž','z');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'š','s');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'č','c');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ř','r');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ď','d');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ť','t');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ň','n');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'ů','u');

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ě','E');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ž','Z');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Š','S');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Č','C');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ř','R');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ď','D');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ť','T');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ň','N');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = REPLACE(post_name,'Ů','U');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET
    post_name = lower(name),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '.', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, ',', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, ';', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, ':', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '?', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '%', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '&', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '#', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '*', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '!', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '_', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '@', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '+', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '(', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, ')', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '[', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, ']', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '/', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '-', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '\'', ''),
    post_name = trim(post_name),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '-', '-'),
    post_name = replace(post_name, '--', '-');

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_name = LOWER(post_name);
```

6. Seems everything works.
7. I also used the plugin '[Rebuild Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rebuild-permalinks/)' just to be sure.